# Email of permanently deleted Facebook account is not reusable

Tags: facebook, account-management

One of my friends hacked my Gmail ID and opened a Facebook account with that ID. Now I have reset password for both Gmail and Facebook account and [deleted](https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account) that Facebook account. But when I want to use my email ID with my existing Facebook account, it is showing that the email ID is associated with another Facebook account.

How can I reuse my existing Gmail ID with my existing Facebook account again?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 12 times. There have been more than ten years since this question was posted. During this time, there have been changed; on the other hand, this might be something that can not be reproduced and that only could have a definitive answer from Facebook. If you are still interested in this, first take a look at sites like [securite.se]. They might be better suited to handle answers like this. However, if you still want to reopen this question, please add more details about the context and elaborate on how this is relevant to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You could reactivate the deleted account, set up a free email account somewhere, associate it with that then delete it. That should then free up your original email address.

Comment: That Facebook account is parmanently deleted.

Comment: have you tried reopening an account with that email address then doing the above?

Comment: @VincePettit: I tried that and I received: *Your account has been disabled. If you have any questions or concerns, you can visit our FAQ page [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=203265519710759).* as if my account was disabled by Facebook for breaching the Terms of Service and not deleted by myself.

Answer (score 0):

A tip that can fix your problem partially:

In Gmail, adding dots in your username has no effect. So `myname@gmail.com` and `my.name@gmail.com` are both the accounts of `myname` and the messages sent to them come in the same inbox.

So you could make a new Facebook account with a different e-mail address based on yours. Facebook will think they are different. But as friends check your account for your e-mail address, they will see the "wrong" address, of course.

EDIT: You will also have to login with your slightly different e-mail address. That can be confusing if you don't use Facebook too often, I recommend you to keep the Facebook welcome e-mail archived.

(Maybe after creating the account, you can change your e-mail to your old e-mail without problems...)

Comment: Not really. Facebook figures out about the dots. At least it does for GMail addresses. I also tried changing to old email address from within - it doesn't work either.

Comment: @GoranJovic Does it?? Wow, that's weird. Facebook shouldn't know that... That's sad, than my answer is no longer valid. I'm sorry I couldn't help.